# Different behavior of cabal repl for library vs. executable

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, ghci, cabal-install

Using `cabal repl` seems to do nothing at all when used on library projects, but works fine for executable projects.  Is this expected behavior that I just don't understand?

If I have a file containing simply

```
go = putStrLn "test"
```

and use `cabal init` with all the defaults (but choose "library" as the type), then running `cabal repl` just produces the some text about configuring and preprocessing the library and never enters a REPL environment.  The exact same steps, but with "executable" selected as the type, puts me right into GHCi as expected.

The code works fine when loaded directly into GHCi.

Comment: Have you specified that file as an exposed module?  I think `cabal repl` will only load it if you have it specified, but that's an untested guess.

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks for the idea, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.  I tried it both with and without the module line and got the same result.

Comment: Well you'd need a named module, but you also need to specify it in you project's cabal file as an included module. Have you tried that too?

Comment: That was it, you were right the first time.  If you want to create a real answer I'd be happy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `cabal repl` to load your modules, you have to first name them in code and then specify them in your project's `.cabal` file as exposed:

---

```
-- MyModule.hs
module MyModule where

go = putStrLn "test"
```

---

```
-- MyProject.cabal
name: MyProject
-- other info ...

library
    exposed-modules: MyModule
    -- other options ...
```

---

Then when you run `cabal repl`, it'll have access to everything in your sandbox (if present) and the exposed modules.  It might also work if you specify them as `other-modules` instead of `exposed-modules`, but I haven't tried that one out.